# Visual artefacts when drawing 2D Function contour plot (using FPlot)

Tags: c#, .net, math, plot

So I use an open source .NET library for plotting: [FPlot](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11608/FPlot-a-NET-library-for-plotting-functions-and-mea)

Here's the function that I'm trying to draw:
f(x,y) = x^2+3*y^2+2*x*y

Here's what I want it to look like:

[image]

Clarification:

1. I don't need the exact same appearence as in the image, I just need the plot to be mathematically correct
2. There are only 10 conours in the picture, I need as much as can be fit on the screen

Here's how I tried to do this:

```
        var graphFunction = new Function2D();
        graphFunction.source = "return (pow(x,2)+3*pow(y,2)+2*x*y)/10;"; 
        /* I'm dividing by 10 because otherwise the whole plot is solid color */
        graphFunction.Compile(true);
```

That's how the FPlot generated plot looks up close:

[image]

This is exactly what I want, but when I zoom out here's what happens:
[image]
Theese **extra ellipses are not supposed to be there**, in fact they are not there, this is just a graphical artefact, because when you zoom into one of theese 'fake' ellipses this is what you see:

[image]

The problem can be in this line:

```
        graphFunction.source = "return (pow(x,2)+3*pow(y,2)+2*x*y)/10;";
```

...or in the FPlot source code. Any Ideas?

**UPDATE:**
So, z value in graph seems to be the problem. When value of a function, z = f(x,y) in a graph exceeds the z1 (max z) value it resets to z = z%z1 (same happens when z is lower then z0), which causes these "lines" - they are not countour lines, like I thought.

So that means the solution is: set z0 to min f(x,y) on screen, and set z1 to max f(x,y) on screen.

Comment: Is there a way to switch on anti-aliasing? Or draw on a canvas 4 times the size and then scale it down?

Comment: I tried messing with all of graph's properties. None of them help in any way

Comment: It's probably the conversion between the actual lines and displaying the pixels, games like minecraft have similar problems when displaying repeating textures from a large distance

Comment: This just appears to be an artifact of digital (discrete) display of a smooth function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the displaying borders of your `FPlotLibrary.GraphControl` have the same value in all 3 dimensions and the problem goes away:

```
        graphControl1.x0 = -40;
        graphControl1.x1 = 40;
        graphControl1.y0 = -40;
        graphControl1.y1 = 40;
        graphControl1.z0 = -40;
        graphControl1.z1 = 40;
```

[image]

Btw, the "problem" reproduces, for instance, if you do

```
        graphControl1.x0 = -40;
        graphControl1.x1 = 40;
        graphControl1.y0 = -40;
        graphControl1.y1 = 40;
        graphControl1.z0 = -1;
        graphControl1.z1 = 1;
```

[image]

Comment: that's it, I completly forgot about z scale. Thank you